# AWS API REST connected to external MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, amazon-web-services, api

I made an API REST with Spring boot, connected to an existing MySQL database. This database is not hosted on my local.

The API works fine on my local but I want to deploy it on AWS.

Is it possible to use this remote MySQL database or do I need to use a new one hosted on AWS?

If it is possible, can you guys link any tutorial or documentation? I can't find anything related to this particular issue.

Thank you!

Comment: you have to set your remote database information in application.properties file in spring framework

Answer (score 0):

yes, AWS does not limit you to using only their RDS (Relational Database Services) offerings. Configuration of the DB will be the same (or similar if you want to use other instance than one used for your local development) as for your local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Application hosted in aws can be connected to both cloud db and on-perm dB.only thing we need to check is security groups configured in ec2 along with other DB configurations.